# Enable debug logs in `ng build`

Tags: angular-cli, angular-compiler-cli

How do I enable debug logs in ng build ? I want to see what the `basePath` is. The snippet below is from `program_based_entry_point_finder.js`.

`node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\entry_point_finder\program_based_entry_point_finder.js`

```
    ProgramBasedEntryPointFinder.prototype.walkBasePathForPackages = function (basePath) {
        var _this = this;
        this.logger.debug("No manifest found for " + basePath + " so walking the directories for entry-points.");
        var entryPoints = utils_1.trackDuration(function () { return _this.entryPointCollector.walkDirectoryForPackages(basePath); }, function (duration) { return _this.logger.debug("Walking " + basePath + " for entry-points took " + duration + "s."); });
        this.entryPointManifest.writeEntryPointManifest(basePath, entryPoints);
        return entryPoints;
    };
```

- Tried to pass --verbose and --configuration="development" without success.

  `ng build --verbose --configuration="development"`
- Angular configuration specification doesn't seem to have any option to change log level.
  https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config

Answer (score -2):

```
"build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "verbose": true
       }
}
```

Then build using:

```
ng build --verbose
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**